# How can I select data between an hour range without using extract?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to select data between an hour range, without using extract to be able to use the indexes in the table. I do the query like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    activities
WHERE   "dateParam"::timestamp >= '21:00:00'::timestamp
AND     "dateParam"::timestamp <= '23:00:00'::timestamp;
```

But I get an 22007 state and it doesnt work, how could I be able to do it?

Comment: Why are you casting `dateParam` to a `timestamp`? If that column stores a timestamp it should also be defined as a `timestamp`.

Comment: Show the index you are trying to use. And show the exact column definition of `"dateParam"`. The expression `"dateParam"::timestamp` is suspicious, like a_horse said.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    activities
WHERE   "dateParam"::timestamp >= current_date + '21:00:00'::time
AND     "dateParam"::timestamp <= current_date + '23:00:00'::time;
```

A `timestamp` needs a `date` portion so add it.